# How to solve a buffer overrun error/warning in a c program (like this one)?

Tags: c, string, primes, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

I have to do a program that link two strings together, here's what I did:

I've initialized two variables, and they are supposed to store the length of the strings.
I've checked for NULL pointer exceptions.
I've counted the strings.
I've dynamically allocated enough memory to store each letter, plus the NULL pointer.
I've put each character in the result string.

But there's a buffer overrun issue in these lines:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < nprime; i++) {
        result[i] = first[i];
    }
```

It's not the first time I encounter this kind of error/warning, and every time I encounter this warning I don't know how to proceed further to solve it, even if I try to change the variable types from a smaller one to a wider one, the problem persists.

what is your approach when you encounter this kind of error? what do you do to try to fix it?
Do you have a checklist?

This is the minimal reproducible example:

```
char* link( const char* first, const char* second) {
    size_t nprime = 0; 
    size_t nsecond = 0; 

    if (first == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    if (second == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; first[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        nprime++; 
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; second[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        nsecond++; 
    }
    char* result = malloc(nprime + nsecond + 1); 
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nprime; i++) {
        result[i] = first[i]; 
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nsecond; i++) {
        result[nprime + i] = second[i]; 
    }
    result[nprime + nsecond] = 0; 

    return result;
```

Comment: Is that a compiler warning? It's because `nprime + nsecond + 1` can overflow `size_t` and is unchecked.

Comment: yes it's a compiler warning, after the allocation I've written the if-check

Comment: Gabriel Burzacchini, "every time I encounter this warning" --> Please post the exact text of the warning.

Comment: What's your compiler (and relevant command-line options) and OS?

Comment: @pmg it's visual studio 2022 on windows 10

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you're right, I update the question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sorry I can't update the question because I have to review the suggested edit before updating it, but I don't have enough reputation to do it, so I write here; "buffer overrun while writing to result the writable size is "nprime+nsecond+1" but two bytes might be written".

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hMKfE3W6o) dos not produce the warning you specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To text for potential overflow in `size_t` addition:

```
// nprime + nsecond + 1
size_t sum = nprime + nsecond + 1u;  // Unsigned math wraps on overflow

// Check if overflow occurred 
if (sum <= nprime) {
  return NULL;   // length too long
}

// char* result = malloc(nprime + nsecond + 1); 
char* result = malloc(sum);
```

Comment: what does "u" after 1 mean?

Comment: `1u` is an `unsigned int` 1 rather than a `signed int` 1.  Since `size_t` is an _unsigned_ type, this keeps the addition as an _unsigned_ addition and not introduce signed/unsigned conversion issues.

Comment: and another question: why did you write "sum<=nprime" and not "sum<=nprime+nsecond+1u" instead?

Comment: and last question (I promise): can I use this check every time I have to use malloc?

Comment: On a rare machine `int` is wider than `size_t`.  In that case `nprime+nsecond+1u` is _always_ more than `sum`, yet `sum` may still be the result of overflow.

Comment: Every time? it really depends on how the size needs are being computed.  This works in the simple addition case here.